# images inside table in CSS , HTML

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, css-position

When I open the page in the half screen it appears like this

[image: The Way half Screen appears]

but when I open it full Screen it appears like this

[image: The Way Full Screen appears]

I tried adding min and `max-width` but I can't figure out where is the problem

```css
.Price {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.infoS {
  background-color: #da9b48;
  color: rgb(31, 22, 5);
  padding: 3px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.Pinfo {
  font-size: 7pt;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="infoS">
    <p class="Pinfo">
      PIXMA G640
    </p>
    <img src="./images/PIXMA G640.png" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
    <p class="Price">
      Price : 150$
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="infoS">
    <p class="Pinfo">
      PIXMA TS7440
    </p>
    <img src="./images/PIXMA TS7440.png" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
    <p class="Price">
      Price : 250$
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="infoS">
    <p class="Pinfo">
      PIXMA G540
    </p>
    <img src="./images/PIXMA G540.png" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
    <p class="Price">
      Price : 170$
    </p>
    <td class="infoS">
      <p class="Pinfo">
        PIXMA G540
      </p>
      <img src="./images/PIXMA G540.png" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
      <p class="Price">
        Price : 120$
      </p>
    </td>
    </tr>



</table>
```

Comment: Tables aren't really the right mechanism for layout. They're generally only appropriate for textual data. Look into CSS Grid or Flexbox.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I want them to appear next to each other like the half screen looks I don't want them to appear like this

Comment: okay I'm on it right now

Answer (score 0):

****Your code is also missing a closing `tr` and a missing `td` tag.**

For the solution, I would suggest you to use 'display: inline-flex' and `justify-content: space-evenly` for this case.

```css
.Price {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.infoS {
  background-color: #da9b48;
  color: rgb(31, 22, 5);
  padding: 3px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.Pinfo {
  font-size: 7pt;
}

tr.row {
  width: 100vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="infoS">
      <p class="Pinfo">
        PIXMA G640
      </p>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/977/536/354.jpg?hmac=slVWYbVbxWnJGkpSJ9FX_iXkIBqJAupfNrNR1CWBoAQ" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
      <p class="Price">
        Price : 150$
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="infoS">
      <p class="Pinfo">
        PIXMA TS7440
      </p>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/977/536/354.jpg?hmac=slVWYbVbxWnJGkpSJ9FX_iXkIBqJAupfNrNR1CWBoAQ" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
      <p class="Price">
        Price : 250$
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="infoS">
      <p class="Pinfo">
        PIXMA G540
      </p>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/977/536/354.jpg?hmac=slVWYbVbxWnJGkpSJ9FX_iXkIBqJAupfNrNR1CWBoAQ" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
      <p class="Price">
        Price : 170$
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="infoS">
      <p class="Pinfo">
        PIXMA G540
      </p>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/977/536/354.jpg?hmac=slVWYbVbxWnJGkpSJ9FX_iXkIBqJAupfNrNR1CWBoAQ" alt="Pixma photo printer" width="75" height="75">
      <p class="Price">
        Price : 120$
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://Your%20code%20is%20also%20missing%20a%20closing%20%60tr%60%20and%20a%20missing%20%60td%60%20tag.)